# Select item and move it to container

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is that user can click on item in one div container and if he clicked then that item fallows mouse. And then he can put that item inside another div but only if the selected item is same type as item container is. Here I include code which I currently made.

**Things I am missing are:**

- item fallows the mouse
- user can return item back

  - if user placed item to container then he can pull it out and put it back where are all items at first time **but it now have to be the last one**
  - or he can pull it out and **put to another** container wich is same type as item

Here is the HTML and JS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script>
  var item_selected=false;
  var item_type=0;
  var item_mouseover=false;
  function itemclicked(item_id,item_t,e_item){
    if(item_selected){return;}
    item_selected=e_item;
    e_item.style.display="none";
    item_type=item_t;
    // stick to mouse movements
  }
  function itemmouseover_out(type){
    if(type==1){item_mouseover=true;}
    else{item_mouseover=false;}
  }
  function mouseovercontainer(container,container_type){
    if(item_selected && item_type==container_type && !container.containsitem){
      container.style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
    else{if(item_selected){
      container.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }}
  }
  function mouseoutcontainer(container){
    if(item_selected){
      container.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
  }
  function containerclick(container,container_type){
    if(item_selected && item_type==container_type && !container.containsitem){
      container.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      container.containsitem=true;
      container.style.backgroundImage=item_selected.style.backgroundImage;
      item_selected=false;
      item_type=0;
    }
  }
  function itemscontainer_click(){
    if(item_selected && item_mouseover==false){
      // return that item to div which contains all items
      item_selected.style.display="";
      item_selected=false;
      item_type=0;
    }
  }
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="containers_container" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;border:solid 1px blue;width:300px;height:300px;">
  <div id="container1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container2" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:90px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container3" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
  <div id="container4" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:90px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
  <div id="container5" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container6" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:-40px;margin-left:160px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer

(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
</div>
<div id="items_container" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:330px;border:solid 1px red;width:300px;height:300px;" onclick="itemscontainer_click()">
  <div id="item1" style="float:left;width:30px;height:31px;margin:5px;background-image:url(http://www.sakura-house.com/img/icon/house.jpg);" onclick="itemclicked(1,1,this)" 

onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></div>
  <div id="item2" style="float:left;width:48px;height:48px;margin:5px;background-image:url(http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4286/minicar48en4.png);" onclick="itemclicked(2,2,this)" 

onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></div>
  <div id="item3" style="float:left;width:50px;height:50px;margin:5px;background-image:url(http://www.top-logix.com/pics/thumbs/case-antec900.jpg);" onclick="itemclicked(3,1,this)" 

onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: no single response/comment nothing! :( cmon people at least give a **vote up** for bad title! :D and tell me what should i write as title! :P hehe

Comment: Is it an option to use a library like jquery? Whta you are looking for ist drag&drop, which e.g. jQueryUI supports.

Comment: yes i can use jquery thats not problem! but i dont need drag&drop :D i need click&drop :D hahaha lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something and for now its working great!

I used jQuery and jQuery(New Wave Javascript) for mouse movement "without it dont works :(". Well for now i have it like that but i still missing a thing that i would like to hide mouse while this item is in use so when you <strike>mouseover</strike>(item over) container then it shows if its available or not. Problem is that if i place selected item in the middle of the cursor then mouse is always over that selected image(item) and cant mouseover the container then! ***I will leave this question open so someone can take a look at what i have now and give suggestions!***

Thanks!

**jQuery Mouse Movement:** [jQuery New wave](http://pastesite.com/21490)

**Current code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery_mm.js"></script>
<script>
  var item_selected=false;
  var item_type=0;
  var item_mouseover=false;
  function itemclicked(item_id,item_t,e_item){
    if(item_selected){return;}
    item_selected=e_item;
    e_item.style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("moover").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("moover").src=e_item.src;
    item_type=item_t;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      //$("#moover").show();
      $("#moover").css({
        top: (e.pageY+15) + "px",
        left: (e.pageX+15) + "px"
      });
    });
  }
  function itemmouseover_out(type){
    if(type==1){item_mouseover=true;}
    else{item_mouseover=false;}
  }
  function mouseovercontainer(container,container_type){
    if(item_selected && item_type==container_type && !container.containsitem){
      container.style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
    else{if(item_selected){
      container.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }}
  }
  function mouseoutcontainer(container){
    if(item_selected){
      container.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
  }
  function containerclick(container,container_type){
    if(item_selected && item_type==container_type && !container.containsitem){
      container.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      container.containsitem=item_selected;
      container.style.backgroundImage='url('+item_selected.src+')';
      //$(document).unbind('mousemove');
      document.getElementById("moover").style.display="none";
      //document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      item_selected=false;
      item_type=0;
    }
    else{if(!item_selected && container.containsitem){
      item_selected=container.containsitem;
      //e_item.style.display="none";
      container.style.backgroundImage="";
      document.getElementById("moover").style.display="";
      document.getElementById("moover").src=item_selected.src;
      item_type=container_type;
      container.containsitem="";
      $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $("moover").show();
        $("#moover").css({
          top: (e.pageY+15) + "px",
          left: (e.pageX+15) + "px"
        });
      });
    }}
  }
  function itemscontainer_click(){
    if(item_selected && item_mouseover==false){
      //$(document).unbind('mousemove');
      document.getElementById("moover").style.display="none";
      //document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      item_selected.style.display="";
      item_selected=false;
      item_type=0;
    }
  }
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="containers_container" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:20px;border:solid 1px blue;width:300px;height:300px;">
  <div id="container1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container2" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:90px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container3" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
  <div id="container4" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:90px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
  <div id="container5" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:30px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,1)" onclick="containerclick(this,1)"></div>
  <div id="container6" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-top:-40px;margin-left:160px;border:solid 1px brown;background:yellow;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" onmouseout="mouseoutcontainer(this)" onmouseover="mouseovercontainer(this,2)" onclick="containerclick(this,2)"></div>
</div>
<div id="items_container" style="position:absolute;top:20px;left:330px;border:solid 1px red;width:300px;height:300px;" onclick="itemscontainer_click()">
  <img id="item1" style="float:left;width:30px;height:31px;margin:5px;" src="http://www.sakura-house.com/img/icon/house.jpg" onclick="itemclicked(1,1,this)" onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></img>
  <img id="item2" style="float:left;width:48px;height:48px;margin:5px;" src="http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/4286/minicar48en4.png" onclick="itemclicked(2,2,this)" onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></img>
  <img id="item3" style="float:left;width:50px;height:50px;margin:5px;" src="http://www.top-logix.com/pics/thumbs/case-antec900.jpg" onclick="itemclicked(3,1,this)" onmouseover="itemmouseover_out(1)" onmouseout="itemmouseover_out(2)"></img>
</div>
<img id='moover' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:none;'></img>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI will make this a lot easier, look at the

Look at the [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) function

Comment: its same like drag&drop... :(

i need that without drag, only click and then fallow mouse and when clicked again then do whatever it has to do! copy paste my code and try so you can see what i need!